start position gym minigrid
I am trying to modify the start position of the agent in the minigrid but "agent_pos" does not seem to work. Would anyone know what to do?
import gym
from gym_minigrid.minigrid import *

# Create the environment
env = gym.make('MiniGrid-Empty-5x5-v0', render_mode="human")

# Reset the environment
observation, info = env.reset(seed = 0)#seed=143)

# Set the agent's starting position
env.agent_pos = (1, 3)  # Example starting position

# Set the goal position
env.grid.set(3, 2, Goal())

# Remove any object at (3, 3) position (optional)
env.grid.set(3, 3, None)

# Render the environment
env.render()

print()


FYI— the markdown syntax for a code block is three backticks (\``), not three single quotes ('''`).

Also, you might consider reviewing [ask] for tips on posing your questions in a manner that best enables the community to assist you.  You've done excellent work in including your code.  However, "does not seem to work" doesn't provide much context.  In what way does it fail to work?  Does the program crash, o ris the output just not what you would expect?  Generally you should aim to include the steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior, as well as any error messages you might see.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Sorry let me clarify the agent's position is unchanged from the start when I use agent_pos. I am therefor uncertain and cannot find any examples how to set the agent's position to a different location. No errors are created in the code. The agent's position just is not changed.
